# How do I dynamically remove items from the checkboxlist

Tags: c#, sqldatasource, checkboxlist

I have a `CheckBoxList` which is bound by an `SqlDataSource` control. I want to remove some items from that list according to some conditions when the page loads.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple options:

1. change the [`SelectCommand`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.selectcommand(v=vs.110).aspx) accordingly
2. use [`cbl.Items.Remove(item)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yhez99sc(v=vs.110).aspx) or [`cbl.Items.RemoveAt(index)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitemcollection.removeat(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I tried the second option (cbl.Items.Remove(item)). But somehow it is not working. The items are still there. Where do I add that code? I had added it in the Page_Load function.

Answer (score 0):

Your SqlDataSource should have a selectCommand which references parameters:

```
SELECT * FROM [tag] where ([name] like @nameFilter)
```

You can then set the values for those parameters:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
            SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add("nameFilter", "value");
            FormView1.DataBind();
     }
```